# Firebase doesn't add documents after bulk user creation

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

### Background

I'm trying to seed my Firebase with a list of initial users in the web app. This should be a two-step process:

- Add user to Firebase Auth using the [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) method.
- Add user to a Firestore collection using the `collection.add()` method.

### Code

```
// Initialize Firebase:

var db = firebase.initializeApp(config).firestore();

// Function to add a new user:

function add(email) {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 'password')
    .then(function (user) {
      console.log('User created:', email, user.user.uid);
      return db.collection('users').add({
        email: email,
        uid: user.user.uid
      });
    })
    .then(function () {
      console.log('Document created:', email);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Could not create user/document:', error);
    });
}

// Seed database with random users:

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  add(i + '@foo.bar');
}
```

### Problem

The code from the previous section doesn't work. My expectation is that it should create 10 users, and add 10 corresponding documents to the database on success. However, **it adds only part of documents (1-3) to the database**, even though the users are created properly.

### Ideas

I came up with some ideas on the possible reasons why this code doesn't work:

- The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method not only creates a new user, but also performs an automatic **sign in**. Probably, this could lead to some kind of race condition.
- The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a promise with a `UserCredential` object of a newly **signed up** user (I believe). However, I might be wrong, and this object represents a **signed in** user which can be the reason for the race condition from the previous point.
- There is a chance that I'm using promises in a wrong way, because neither the second `then()` nor `catch()` are called.

Comment: Can you try to make them write at different collections? Like... pass `i` as an argument and write at `users1`, `users2`...

Comment: Maybe you could try covert method add to async and then use await in the loop to be sure that all have been finished?

Comment: @Stratubas Still the same, only 1-3 collections are created.

Comment: @vitooh This would do the job, but it still wouldn't reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: You can check if your `catch` works in general by doing something like `collection('users/oops').add(...`

Comment: @vitooh It works, thanks! However, I'm still curious why the promises are not rejected properly.

Comment: ...but I'm afraid your case is not just an error you aren't handling, but it's an error your client never finds out, for some reason.

Comment: @Stratubas Yep, `catch` works fine when I (for example) disallow `write` in the Firebase rules. Moreover, when I run my 10-iteration loop with the same prohibiting rules, it **does** catch 1-3 errors and is still silent about the rest.

Comment: Try to see if there are WebSocket messages regarding the status of your document writes (by inspecting "Network" at dev tools).

Comment: @Stratubas WS tab is empty, however I noticed that the failed add requests are marked as `(canceled)` XHRs.

Comment: So maybe the SDK cancels pending writes when the auth changes? Hmm.

Comment: I think I should try submitting an issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk). Thanks a lot for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Stratubas I recevied an answer from the Firebase support (see the answer), now this behavior makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the excerpt from the Firebase support answer:

> Each time a new user is created with Auth, it sets the newly created user as the current user of the application. Whenever Firestore detects that a user change has occurred, it closes all outstanding streams and **cancels any requests** in flight.

This totally makes sense and explains the behavior.